# Connection for very thin wires

Tags: connector, wire, crimp

I came across some very thin coax cable, maybe 34awg,or even 36. Now i am wondering, foe which industry is it used and what connectors are available there. Any ideas?

Comment: Most likely application is cell phones. The connectors I know of (don't know if they go down to AWG 34 size) are a bunch of proprietary choices from different companies (Hirose is one I know of).

Comment: Very thin coax with small brass connector (e.g. [sma](http://www.wellshow.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/01/sma-connector-plug-300x270.jpg) ) is typically used for antenna connections in small form factors. Commonly seen in wifi routers to connect the external antenna

Comment: @crasic, SMA is absolutely huge compared to some of the stuff available for cell phones. Go have a look at Hirose's H.FL, X.FL, W.FL, etc.

Comment: Thanks!! Hirose looks nice, although the cable is twice as thick.

Answer (score 1):

1.32mm is a common RF Cable size 50 Ohm up to 6Ghz used inside wifi devices. It commonly connects to PCB mount U-FL connector, also supports MMCX connectors and SMA. We're using this cable to connect MMCX connector on a wiFi card inside our wifi router to the SMA antenna connector on the outside, and to do the same thing from U-FL connector on another WiFi card.

Comment: I don't think, this cable is thicker than 0.5mm